# PHPStorm 8 Type Hinting for Node Modules

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, npm

I cannot for the life of me get autocomplete to work on npm modules with node.js

```
var MongoCollection = require('mongodb').Collection;

/**
 * @param {MongoCollection} mongoDbCollection
 * @param cache
 * @constructor
 */
function MongoTest(mongoDbCollection, cache) {
    mongoDbCollection.insert();
}
```

I get a yellow squiggle under my "insert". I am using the DefinitelyTyped mongodb module set to node_module and visible for my project. Anything glaring I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've tried using @param {mongodb.Collection} among others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'Collection' type instead - works even without DefinitelyTyped stuff:

```
var MongoCollection = require('mongodb').Collection;

/**
 * @param {Collection} mongoDbCollection
 * @param cache
 * @constructor
 */
function MongoTest(mongoDbCollection, cache) {
    mongoDbCollection.insert();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, worked great. Any thoughts on why? Should I just avoid all "namespacing" / parent names all together? Thanks.

Comment: full names in type declarations are not yet supported:( See [WEB-7588](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7588) and [WEB-2355](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2355)